# Cordova requirements throwing 'foreach' undefined

Tags: cordova

When running the cordova requirements browser command, I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

It gives me no indication of where the error is stemming from, there is also no `--debug` property for requirements. As far as I am concerned, this error could come from any file in my project.

Comment: I think it's the same error that appears here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13740

Answer (score 0):

You can install cordova `8.1.2` and it will show an stacktrace with `-d`, like:

```
$ cordova requirements -d
PlatformApi successfully found for platform browser
PlatformApi successfully found for platform ios

Requirements check results for browser:
Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js:397:35
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js:388:68
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

That may help you find the error

Answer (score 0):

It's also reported here:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-browser/issues/65

Try updating to the latest nightly build with: `npm install --global cordova@nightly`